# multiple sql queries that depend on each other with a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, eventtrigger, triggers

I have 2 sql queries that i would like to use a trigger for. However, the second one depends on the first sql query and it also does a join and this complicated things quite a bit for me.
Here is my table:

```
id |FB_Followers|TW_Followers|sum_Fans|FB_Fan_Growth_Speed
1     2              4                      
2     6              5
3     4              8
```

Here is my code:

```
USE `my_database`; 
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `followers_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `followers` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
   SET NEW.sum_fans = NEW.FB_Follower+NEW.TW_Followers;   
   update followers f left outer
   join followers f2
   on f2.id = f.id - 1
   set f.FB_Fan_Growth_Speed = f.FB_Followers / f2.FB_Followers; 
END
```

So the first SQL query works perfectly well as it is pretty simple.

```
SET NEW.sum_fans = NEW.FB_Follower+NEW.TW_Followers;
```

The second query is more complicated, im not sure if i should use NEW as well for it. I am basically trying to ake the new row divide by the row before it to get the rate of increase in followers. When not in use in a trigger, this query works perfectly fine.

```
update followers f left outer
       join followers f2
       on f2.id = f.id - 1
       set f.FB_Fan_Growth_Speed = f.FB_Followers / f2.FB_Followers;
```

So i guess my question now is how do i put the first and second query inside a trigger? Or is there any other way i can do it without using a trigger?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trigger for this. First you have to put the previews sum_Fans into prev_sum_Fans variable, something like this:

```
$prev_sum_Fans= SELECT sum_Fans FROM followers WHERE cur_id=cur_id-1;
```

then make the insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO `followers` 
(id,FB_Followers,TW_Followers,sum_Fans,FB_Fan_Growth_Speed)
VALUES
($cur_id, $FB_Followers, $TW_Followers, $FB_Followers+$TW_Followers,$prev_sum_Fans/$sum_Fans);
```